# How to restore deleted Downloads folder

Tags: macos, restore, folders

I accidentally deleted my Downloads folder as well as the sidebar item for it in the process of trying to fix it. How do I get them back?

Comment: **How** did you delete/remove the Downloads folder? The only way I've found to remove it in Sierra is `sudo rm -dR ~/Downloads` in Terminal.app! In the Finder (i.e. dragging the folder into the trash bin) or without `sudo` it isn't possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your download folder may be backed up on iCloud. If not you may have to resort to special recovery options. You can edit your sidebar by going to preferences for the finder. Single click on the desktop so Finder shows in the menu bar. Under Finder is preferences. Opening that and going to tab for sidebar allows you to set what is shown in the sidebar.  But if download folder is truly deleted this won't help much.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply recreate the Downloads folder in your user directory, and it will be 'blessed' by the OS with the custom Downloads folder icon after you restart the computer. You may need to reset this folder path in any apps which specify the Downloads folder by default.